# How to know when a url hash has been manuallly (writing) changed?

Tags: javascript, url, hashchange

is there a way, or a tool (js plugin or other) that let me know when I manually change the hash part of the URL? Note: with 'manual' i mean, I'm here:

```
http://www.[mydomain].com/#hash1
```

and then I cancel and rewrite the hash with mouse/keaboard, OR, clicking back/next browser buttons.

```
http://www.[mydomain].com/#hash2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window object has a `hashchange` event that is fired when url hash changes

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(event){
 console.log('hash change event =>',event);
}, false);
```

Read more from mdn documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: Yes, I just noticed, and the funny thing is that I knew of it but didn't know it reacted to manual changes... :) Another funny thing is that it does NOT react to push/replaceState, but this is another topic.